# Как найти документ по части массива в MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Столкнулся со следующей задачей и не знаю как ее решить.
Ситуация такая, есть документы вида

```
{
 _id: ObjectId
 tags: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
}
```

И есть сам массив

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Все бы ничего и можно было бы просто сделать следующую выборку

```
Coll.find({ tags: ["a", "b", "c"] })
```

Но проблема в том что мне нужно найти только те документы у которых поле tags совпадает именно только по первыми тремя элементами

Думал уже сделать вот так

```
Coll.find({ "tags.0": t[0], "tags.1": t[1], "tags.2": t[2] })
```

И опять проблема, именно в последовательности, мне нужно чтобы независимость от индексов массива, что вроде по того

```
{
    "tags.0": t[0],
    "tags.1": t[1],
    "tags.2": t[2],

    "tags.0": t[1],
    "tags.1": t[0],
    "tags.2": t[2],

    "tags.0": t[2],
    "tags.1": t[0],
    "tags.2": t[1]

    // и т.д.
}
```

Т.е. теги могут идти вперемешку, главное чтобы сравнить два массива не "глубже" tags[2]

Я конечно могу создать группу массивов, но может быть есть варианты получше? Что то вроде какого то splice поля документа перед выборкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
db.test.find({$and: [{"tags.0": {$in: ['a', 'b', 'c']}}, {"tags.1": {$in: ['a', 'b', 'c']}}, {'tags.2': {$in:["a", "b","c"]}} ]})
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо!